# Perforce: Number of files in a submitted changelist

Tags: perforce, p4v, changelist

I have recently submitted a changelist to `Perforce` which contains around 600 files (which were all 'edit', 'add' and 'delete'). Now, the build is broken and I want to check whether I have missed some files from submitting to Perforce.

```
Is there a way to count the number of files in a submitted change-list in Perforce?
```

Comment: `p4 changes -l <CL> | grep '^//' | wc -l`?

Comment: I am on Mac OS and have GUI installed. Is it possible using GUI too? If not, how can I configure command line tool for perforce on Mac?

Comment: p4 GUI anyways limits the output to a certain number of bytes (I don't recall the number off the top of my head).  You could get the command line client from http://www.perforce.com -- you'd simply need to set a few variables `P4USER`, `P4HOST`, `P4CLIENT`, .... and could issue the command from shell on Mac.

Comment: `p4 help command`, e.g. `p4 help changes` would give the documentation for the command in question.  The documentation is reasonable and you shouldn't have any issues trying to set it up or start using it.

Comment: p4 files //...@=<CL> | wc -l should work, too.

Comment: Another thing you might try is to run 'reconcile offline work' from P4V, and see if it finds any files in your workspace that should have been added.

Comment: Personally I have a script that dumps the files (and only the files) in a given CL (example is for Windows, substitute `%1` with your OS's "first argument" syntax: 

`p4 describe -s %1 | perl -ne"print if s/^\.{3} (.*)#.*/$1/"`

...then like @devnull says, pipe that to `wc -l`.

Answer (score 2):

In the P4V GUI, go to Edit->Preferences->Display. There's a checkbox for "Show item count on tab bar of details pane". If you check that, then go to the Submitted Changes tab, click on your changelist, it'll display how many files are in the change on the "Files" tab of the details underneath the list.

It's a bit of a performance hit as it will run extra commands to populate those numbers as you're navigating around the lists in P4V. So if you notice performance starting to be an issue, turn the preference back off.

Comment: +1, note that you shouldn't double-click on the submitted changelist: just select the changelist with a single click and the files tab below will show the number of files.I don't know why I thought I had to doubleclick in the first place -> the changelist details do not contain this information

Comment: Nah, there's an open request to have the file count in that submitted form window too, but I haven't gotten around to it yet. :)